# Deploying a Change Set would deploy the Case Reason Picklist updates?

Tags: case, picklist, record-type

This is very generic question I had before I do a major deployment. We have **Case Reason** picklist which is being used in almost 20 Case Record types with different values for each.

I have updated(replaced/removed/added) those picklist values in all the record types. Now my question is, if I deploy those record types would carry the changes I made to the **Case Reason** picklist values as well? Or should I do those changes again in the Target org manually?

Comment: Clone your production org into a sandbox, and deploy your changes to that sandbox. Im sure theres other changes you'd like to check before the deploy, and this is the best way to check them.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Going back to my question, will the picklist needed to be deployed manually? Or it will be deployed as a part of the Record Type? :)